# React - How to apply blur effect to my SideBar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, sidebar

I created a SideBar on my React application, at the moment I need to apply a blur effect to my SideBar, something like this

[image]

Here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-shadow-3gmgf) to my codesandbox project, I removed the logic and functionality, leaving only the design in order to make it easier to work

Comment: your sideBar has already a blur effect in your code sandbox. What do you need ?

Comment: Yes, you are right after I asked the question I was able to apply a blurred effect, but please pay attention to the background with the picture, the picture is applied to the <body> and I want it to be displayed only inside the sidebar

Comment: I found something but It's not enough to be an answer [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-snowflake-4bq2l).
hope it helps